# xmllint validation error for ID attribute

Tags: xml, xml-validation, dtd, xmllint

I'm trying to validate this XML document:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<CONTACTS>
    <CONTACT CONTACT_NUM = "1">
    <NAME>Alice</NAME>
    </CONTACT>

    <CONTACT CONTACT_NUM = "2">
    <NAME>Bob</NAME>
    </CONTACT>
</CONTACTS>
```

against the following DTD:

```
<!ELEMENT CONTACTS ANY>
<!ELEMENT CONTACT (NAME)>
<!ELEMENT NAME (#PCDATA)>
<!ATTLIST CONTACT CONTACT_NUM ID #REQUIRED>
```

running 
`xmllint --dtdvalid test.dtd test.xml`
produces:

```
test.xml:3: element CONTACT: validity error : Syntax of value for attribute CONTACT_NUM of CONTACT is not valid
test.xml:7: element CONTACT: validity error : Syntax of value for attribute CONTACT_NUM of CONTACT is not valid
Document test.xml does not validate against test.dtd
```

Anybody spot what's wrong with the syntax of attribute CONTACT_NUM?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The value of an attribute of type ID cannot start with a digit. It must match the `Name` production in the XML specification, which rules out initial digits.

`<CONTACT CONTACT_NUM = "_1">` or `<CONTACT CONTACT_NUM = "ID1">` would be OK, for example.

References:

- http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-attribute-types
- http://www.w3.org/TR/xml/#sec-common-syn